# Why do I get: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: WebSocket closed with status code: 1006 (no reason given) after 1-2 minutes

Tags: signalr, plesk

I have a multi user game using SignalR 6.0.6, .Net 8.0, c# on the server, JavaScript and TypeScript on the client. Built with Visual Studio. It is hosted on a GoDaddy server managed with Plesk.

All was going fine, then suddenly I keep getting

`Error: WebSocket closed with status code: 1006 (no reason given)`

This happens 1-2 minutes after opening the website. It happens even if I do nothing in the game. I just sit and watch the inactive screen until the error pops up.

Previously I fixed the problem by Resetting account in Plesk and republishing. This does not work any longer. I have looked at some of the similar questions and none seem to be relevant to this problem.

Anybody got any ideas?

**Two days later**, sadly the suggestions don't help. I built the [Microsoft SignalR JavaScript sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio). It works fine in VS debug but fails just like my app when published to the GoDaddy server. They still say "there is something wrong with your [Microsoft's] code".

I have given up :-(

Comment: What makes you think that this is directly related to Plesk itself?

Comment: I dont know! I am on the phone to Godaddy support now ... They are fiddling about in Plesk.

Comment: Finished now. They blame my software! I will now try going back to signalR basics and seeing if the server works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=WebSocket+closed+with+status+code%3A+1006